# How to stop an add to cart button redirecting users

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change my `add to cart` button on my website. At the moment I have to go to a specific item page to add the actual item to the cart.

I have an `add to cart` button on the category page for a group of items but this when clicked redirects the users to the shopping basket.

A. Can i change this to just add one item and not redirect?

B. Can i integrate a quantity box easily that adds the amount of items specified to the cart. As at the moment i cannot get the quantity box to work with the button click

```
      <div class="action">
          <input type="button" value="[category_buyitlink]" onclick="window.location ='add_cart.asp?quick=1&amp;item_id=[catalogid]'" class="btn" onmouseover="this.className='btn_over'" onmouseout="this.className='btn'" />
          <input type="text" size="3" name="qty-0" value="0" class="txtBoxStyle"> <!--Quantity box-->
       </div>
```

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Don't this so, he is changing the window location not submitting a form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the element is automatically added to the shopping cart when you visit `add_cart.asp` and pass it the parameters, you can simply use a GET request to that resource instead of navigating the client there:

So instead of using

```
<input type="button" value="[category_buyitlink]" onclick="window.location ='add_cart.asp?quick=1&amp;item_id=[catalogid]'" ...
```

you would create a function that does the GET request when clicking the button, like this one:

```
function get(theUrl, callback)
{
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
            callback(xmlHttp.responseText);
    }
    xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, true); // true for asynchronous 
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
<input type="button" value="[category_buyitlink]" onclick="get('add_cart.asp?quick=1&amp;item_id=[catalogid]', res => console.log(res));" ...
```

To add the quantity to the request, you could modify the function `get` a little to also accept a third parameter called `quantity` that is appended to the URL, you jus need to figure out how to handle this in your backend:

```js
function get(theUrl, quantity, callback) {
  var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
      callback(xmlHttp.responseText);
  }
  xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl+`&quantity=${quantity}`, true); // true for asynchronous 
  xmlHttp.send(null);
}
```

Now this is passing the quantity as a URL parameter, just like `quick=1` and `item_id=[catalog_id]`. You can use it on you button like so:

```
<input type="button" value="[category_buyitlink]" onclick="get('add_cart.asp?quick=1&amp;item_id=[catalogid]', document.querySelector('input[name=qty-0').value , res => console.log(res));" ...
```

The call to the `get` function now looks like this:

```
get('add_cart.asp?quick=1&amp;item_id=[catalogid]', document.querySelector('input[name=qty-0').value , res => console.log(res);
```

Comment: Instead of theUrl would this be add_cart.asp ?

Comment: As you can see in the last bit of code I posted, the `onclick` handler now runs `get('add_cart.asp?quick=1&amp;item_id=[catalogid]', res => console.log(res);` instead of changing the window location, there you have your URL

Comment: Ahhhh i see well it does work the only issue is the basket isn't shown to update until you go to the baskets page, but thankyou for the help so far. I take it, i could also use this method to include a value from the quantity box?

Comment: If you want to update the cart, you can do that in the second parameter to the `get` function, in my example i just console.log whatever "add_cart.asp" returns, but you could return the number of elements to the client and then change the cart image

Comment: If you give me a few minutes I'll add an example of how to also add the quantity

Comment: I also had an error in the first example for the new <button>

Comment: Thankyou very much for the help. Yea it's code i've adopted and i'm a VERY new web dev.  The quick=1 is always adding one to the quantity so it's causing a bit of jip.

Comment: If the answer helped you, please consider upvoting and marking it as answered ;-)